# Background Process stdout Displays After Next Command

Tags: bash

I am running a process in a sub-shell which may or may not hang, then killing that process if it is still running after 10 seconds.

In doing so, I pipe `stdout` and `stderr` to /dev/null with `> /dev/null 2>&1`, which seems to work. However, the output of the kill command then prints to `stdout` after my next command, no matter what command I use.

```
[me@test] (Command_That_May_Hang.sh)&
[me@test] X=$!
[me@test] (sleep 10 && kill -9 $! > /dev/null 2>&1)&
[me@test] ps
>   PID TTY          TIME CMD
> 22741 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
> 27585 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
> [1]+  Killed                  Command_That_May_Hang.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have tried moving `/dev/null 2>&1` to the outside of `()` and even after `&`, with no change in results. For reference, those iterations look like:

```
(sleep 10 && kill -9 $!) > /dev/null 2>&1 &
(sleep 10 && kill -9 $!)& > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Executing the process and then killing it both work successfully, it just seems that I can only *temporarily* suppress the output, which is strange behavior. Any help on correctly sending output to `/dev/null` would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any output from `kill`. What are you referring to?

Comment: Your redirections only apply to the individual commands they're run against. If you want to suppress output from `Command_That_May_Hang`, then you need to run `Command_That_May_Hang >/dev/null 2>&1`. Suppressing output from the `kill` has no impact on whether the separate program that is the *target* of that `kill` writes output.

Comment: nit: "I pipe stdout and stderr" is incorrect. You are redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null. No pipe is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is printed by bash itself, not by the `kill` command. So you can't suppress it by redirecting any output in your script.

What you can do is to disable the monitor mode of job control by executing

```
set +m
```

Quote from the bash man page:

> **-m** Monitor  mode.   Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for
>   interactive shells on systems that support it (see JOB CONTROL above).  All
>   processes run in a separate  process group.  When a background job
>   completes, the shell prints a line containing its exit status.

With a `+m` the monitor mode is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

#### Speaking to *actual* subprocess output, not shell diagnostic status

As I understand it, you want to suppress output from your program only after it's received a kill signal.

You can't do that by redirecting the output from `kill` itself; you can *only* do that by changing how the program itself has its output directed at startup time.

In the following example, we redirect stdout and stderr of your command to a separate shell process, and tell that shell process to stop printing output when it receives a SIGUSR1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.[012]) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.3 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

process_output_until_signal() {
  running=1
  trap 'running=0' USR1
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( running )) && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
}
exec 3> >(process_output_until_signal); output_loop_pid=$!
Command_That_May_Hang >&3 2>&3 & command_pid=$!
exec 3>&-

sleep 10
kill -USR1 "$output_loop_pid"
sleep 0.1
kill "$command_pid"
```

---

#### Speaking to shell diagnostic status

See [the answer by Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335338/14122): This is output written *by the shell*, not by the `kill` command, and also not by the command that was killed. (It's also written only when the command is running in a configuration that's enabled by default only for interactive shells and not for scripts).

Comment: I'm pretty sure "*the kill command*" literally refers to `kill`, not "the killed command".

Comment: @melpomene, they're redirecting output from `kill` itself, which is why I believe it was appropriate to speak to it.